# How to enable private browsing for Safari in the Protractor configuration

Tags: javascript, safari, protractor, automated-tests

I've been searching for a way to enable private browsing for Safari in the protractor conf file. I have gotten chrome to work with private browsing, with the below

```
 chromeOptions: {
   args: ["incognito", "disable-extensions"]
}
```

I havent found anything similar with Safari, if anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to enable "incognito" with protractor?  It automatically uses a fresh browser with no cookies or history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the WebDriver's documentation, what you are looking for is the 
**`cleanSession`** property. It makes sure the session has no cookies, cache entries, local storage, or databases.

[You can learn more here about Safari specific options.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#safari-specific)